# Correct way to implement auto-update feature for PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt, updates, zip

I'm nearly finished with a PyQt application for Windows, which I would like to have automatically update from a ZIP archive hosted on a remote server.

I have most of the update script complete, with it correctly downloading the new source and extracting it. My final step is to stop the software, replace the old source and restart the app.

My question is about which of the following is more appropriate:

1. to run the updater script through a system call to python and killing the software using python.
2. run the updater script using a system call to a batch file that kills the main software before overwriting it's source.
3. import the updater as a module and perform all of it's actions in the same process as the main software.

I can provide the scripts if necessary.

UPDATE:

So I've been exploring all the ways to do this including using multiprocessing (which produced a child process that was killed along with the parent) and subprocess.

The latter apparently can run the child process separately, which will allow me to shutdown the main app before extracting the new source. Here's what I have working:

```
@staticmethod
def install(folder):
    # stop Pierre, unpack newest version, then restart Pierre.
    try:
        with open('pierre.pid', mode='r') as pid:
            os.kill(int(pid.read()), signal.SIGINT)

        with zipfile.ZipFile(file=folder) as zipped:
            zipped.extractall(path='src')

        try:
            pierre = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.getcwd()), 'src/pierre.py')
            exec(pierre)
        except OSError as exc:
            logging.error("Restarting Pierre failed. " + str(exc))

        try:
            os.remove('src.zip')
        except OSError as exc:
            logging.error("Deletion of zip failed. " + str(exc))

    except zipfile.BadZipFile:
        logging.error("Pierre update file is corrupt.")

    except Exception as exc:
        logging.error("Pierre update install failed. " + str(exc))
```

What's not working:

```
@staticmethod
def update_process():
    # Begin the update process by spawning the updater script.
    script = 'python ' + os.getcwd() + '\\updater.py'
    subprocess.Popen([script])
```

The subprocess is producing a `FileNotFoundError` despite the path working when run manually in command prompt. (The second method is what starts the script, leading to the first method.)

Comment: Have you tried any of those methods?

Comment: @eyllanesc I've been working on the third option, but I'm having trouble a method with which to kill the main process without ending the updater script as well.

Comment: @smallpants: shows us what you got so far (code)

Comment: @Skandix updated the OP.

Answer (score 1):

I've got it. Here's what the process spawner looks like now:

```
@staticmethod
def update_process():
    # Begin the update process by spawning the updater script.
    script = os.path.join(os.getcwd() + '/updater.py')
    script = script.replace('\\', '/')
    subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, script], shell=True)
```

This launches the separate updater script.